# On click of a button, execute onLongClick map in SupportMapsFragment

Tags: android, google-maps

I know how to detect the Maps onLongClick listener inside of the SupportMapsFragement. To make this feature a little intuitive, I have a button inside the Maps, which allows the user to add a Geofence. So now my requirement is, when the user clicks on the button, I want the screen to be transparent, asking the user to long click anywhere on the map. Once the user longClicks on the Map, I want to execute the onMapLongClickListener.

Is there a way I can do this? Any help is appreciated. I am not able to figure out how to do this. Please find below what I have tried so far.

**MapsFragment.java**

```
mMap.setOnMapLongClickListener(new GoogleMap.OnMapLongClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onMapLongClick(LatLng latLng) {

            databaseReference.child("latitude").setValue(latLng.latitude);
            databaseReference.child("longitude").setValue(latLng.longitude);


            if (!geoSetAlready) {

                setMap(latLng);
            }

        }
    });

public void setMap(LatLng latLng) {
    BitmapDrawable bitmapdraw = (BitmapDrawable) getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.logoga);
    Bitmap b = bitmapdraw.getBitmap();
    Bitmap smallMarker = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(b, 200, 200, false);
    latlangForGeo = latLng;
    MarkerOptions markerOptions = new MarkerOptions()
            .position(latLng)
            .title("name display")
            .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromBitmap(smallMarker));
    CircleOptions circleOptions1 = new CircleOptions()
            .center(latLng)
            .strokeColor(Color.argb(50, 70, 70, 70))
            .fillColor(Color.argb(200, 00, 150, 00))
            .radius(geofenceradius[0]);
    CircleOptions circleOptions2 = new CircleOptions()
            .center(latLng)
            .strokeColor(Color.argb(50, 70, 70, 70))
            .fillColor(Color.argb(50, 100, 00, 00))
            .radius(geofenceradius[1]);
    CircleOptions circleOptions3 = new CircleOptions()
            .center(latLng)
            .strokeColor(Color.argb(50, 70, 70, 70))
            .fillColor(Color.argb(50, 255, 0, 0))
            .radius(geofenceradius[2]);
    mMap.addMarker(markerOptions);
    mCircle = mMap.addCircle(circleOptions1);
    mCircle = mMap.addCircle(circleOptions2);
    mCircle = mMap.addCircle(circleOptions3);
    mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(latLng, 5));
    // Zoom in, animating the camera.
    mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomIn());
    // Zoom out to zoom level 10, animating with a duration of 2 seconds.
    mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(10), 1000, null);
    geoSetAlready = true;
}
```

And this is my layout class.

```
<fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
xmlns:fab="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:id="@+id/map"
android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="com.project.group.projectga.fragments.GuardianMapsFragment">


<com.getbase.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionsMenu
    android:id="@+id/fab_menu"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="start|top"
    fab:fab_expandDirection="down"
    fab:fab_addButtonColorNormal="@color/loginbackground"
    fab:fab_addButtonColorPressed="@color/Map"
    fab:fab_addButtonPlusIconColor="@color/Map"
    fab:fab_addButtonStrokeVisible="false"
    fab:fab_labelStyle="@style/menu_labels_style"
    fab:fab_labelsPosition="right">

    <com.getbase.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab_calendar"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        fab:fab_colorNormal="@color/loginbackground"
        fab:fab_colorPressed="@color/loginbackground"
        fab:fab_icon="@drawable/ic_clear_all_yellow_24dp"
        fab:fab_plusIconColor="@color/Map"
        fab:fab_size="mini"
        fab:fab_title="@string/remove_geofences" />

    <com.getbase.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab_clear"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        fab:fab_colorNormal="@color/loginbackground"
        fab:fab_colorPressed="@color/loginbackground"
        fab:fab_icon="@drawable/ic_add_yellow_24dp"
        fab:fab_plusIconColor="@color/Map"
        fab:fab_size="mini"
        fab:fab_title="@string/add_geofences" />


</com.getbase.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionsMenu>
```